# How can i change a datagridview cell text according to what file was downloaded?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

In the constructor

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = false;
            label4.Visible = false;
            label7.Visible = false;

            tbxMainDownloadPath.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.LastSelectedFolder;
            if (tbxMainDownloadPath.Text != "")
                downloadDirectory = tbxMainDownloadPath.Text;

            tracker = new DownloadProgressTracker.DownloadProgress(50, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
            string[] countries = File.ReadAllLines(@"CountriesNames.txt");
            string[] countriesCodes = File.ReadAllLines(@"CountriesCodes.txt");
            foreach (string country in countries)
            {
                countryList.Add(country);
                string countryPath = Path.Combine(downloadDirectory, country);
                if (!Directory.Exists(countryPath))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(countryPath);
            }
            foreach (string code in countriesCodes)
            {
                codesList.Add(code);
            }
            codeToFullNameMap = codesList
                .Select((code, index) => index)
                .ToDictionary(
                              keySelector: index => codesList[index],
                              elementSelector: index => countryList[index]);

            lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"links.txt");

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                RichTextBoxExtensions.AppendText(true, richTextBox1, "Ready: ", Color.Red, 8.25f);
                richTextBox1.AppendText(lines[i] + (i < lines.Length - 1 ? Environment.NewLine : String.Empty));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < countriesCodes.Length; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Status";
                dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Country";
                var countryName = codeToFullNameMap[countriesCodes[i]];
                string[] row = new string[] { "Ready", countryName };
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
                DataGridViewLinkColumn dgvLink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
                dgvLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
                dgvLink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
                dgvLink.HeaderText = "Link Data";
                dgvLink.Name = "SiteName";
                dgvLink.LinkColor = Color.Blue;
                dgvLink.TrackVisitedState = true;
                dgvLink.Text = lines[i];
                dgvLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvLink);
            }
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

            DataGridViewCellStyle mystyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            mystyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
            mystyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Red;
            dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle = mystyle;

            dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;

            dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

When running the program

[image: datagridview]

Then when start downloading when the first file download completed i'm changing the Status from Ready in Red to Downloaded in Green:

```
private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                // handle error scenario
                throw e.Error;
            }
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                // handle cancelled scenario
            }

            if (url.Contains("animated") && url.Contains("infra"))
            {
                Image img = new Bitmap(lastDownloadedFile);
                Image[] frames = GetFramesFromAnimatedGIF(img);
                foreach (Image image in frames)
                {
                    countFrames++;
                    image.Save(downloadDirectory + "\\" + fname + ".gif");
                }
            }

            RichTextBoxExtensions.UpdateText(richTextBox1, "Ready: ", "Downloaded: ", Color.Green);
            label2.Text = "Download Complete";

                DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "Downloaded";
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.SelectionForeColor = Color.Green;
            tracker.NewFile();
            DownloadFile();
        }
```

After downloaded a file

[image: Downloaded]

The problem is that it's allways cell[0]
How can i find what link/file that have been downloaded and change the cell value to the right index ?

For example if there was an error in the completed event i want to change the correct cell index value to "Error" in red. If the file downloaded without any problems change the right cell index to "Downloaded" in green.

The problem is how to find the correct cell index ?

And the method where i register the completed event.
I call this method from a button click event.

```
private void DownloadFile()
        {
            if (_downloadUrls.Any())
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += client_DownloadProgressChanged;
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += client_DownloadFileCompleted;

                url = _downloadUrls.Dequeue();

                if (url.Contains("animated") && url.Contains("infra"))
                {
                    string startTag = "animated/";
                    string endTag = "/infra";

                    int index = url.IndexOf(startTag);
                    int index1 = url.IndexOf(endTag);

                    fname = url.Substring(index + 9, index1 - index - 9);
                    var countryName = codeToFullNameMap[fname];
                    downloadDirectory = tbxMainDownloadPath.Text;
                    downloadDirectory = Path.Combine(downloadDirectory, countryName);
                }
                else
                {
                    fname = "Tempfile";
                    downloadDirectory = tbxMainDownloadPath.Text;
                }

                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), downloadDirectory + "\\" + fname + ".gif");
                lastDownloadedFile = downloadDirectory + "\\" + fname + ".gif";

                return;
            }

            // End of the download
            label2.Text = "All files have been downloaded";
        }
```

And last the progresschanged event

```
void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            tracker.SetProgress(e.BytesReceived, e.TotalBytesToReceive);
            pBarFileProgress.Value = (int)(tracker.GetProgress() * 100.0);
            label3.Text = e.BytesReceived + "/" + e.TotalBytesToReceive;
            label7.Text = tracker.GetBytesPerSecondString();
            label2.Text = "Downloading";
            label4.Text = downloadDirectory + "\\" + fname + ".gif";
        }
```

And the downloadfile method that add the urls to a queue

```
private void downloadFile(IEnumerable<string> urls)
        {
            foreach (var url in urls)
            {
                _downloadUrls.Enqueue(url);
            }

            // Starts the download
            btnStart.Text = "Downloading...";
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            pBarFileProgress.Visible = true;

            DownloadFile();

            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
            label3.Text = "";
            label7.Text = "";
            label2.Text = "";
            label4.Text = "";
        }
```

Comment: How does your `DataGridViewLinkColumn.CellContentClick` event handler look like. Hopefully the event handler will show code for registering `client_DownloadFileCompleted`, else you should also show code which registers the `client_DownloadFileCompleted` event and related to it

Comment: FYI, your constructor code where you loop to add data does not make sense. You should separate the code which sets up the columns and which adds the row data (preferably into separate functions). If you have 100 rows, then currently you set the columns 100 times which is completely unnecessary. Also to fix your problem, you need to pass some `UserState` data to the async downloading Task like the link itself, so you can search the table on `DownloadFileCompleted` event and update the corresponding row's first column

Comment: @Vikhram edited my question with the part where i register the completed event.

Comment: @Vikhram i will try to do it. But if you could post an answer for this two problems the constructor and the completed event later it will be great.

Comment: @Vikhram i used async await and task before but not sure how to do it now with my code.

Comment: Updated my question with the whole constructor code and added also the progresschanged event. It seems hard to add and use the task async part.

Comment: I forgot to add to my question the downloadFile method not DownloadFile it's a different method and in this one i'm adding the urls to a queue and this way i'm downloading each time the next file. I'm not downloading the same file numerous times.

Comment: I still don't see any code which initiates the download when user clicks the link in `DataGridViewLinkColumn`. If you have this work in a working project that can be shared, I can help you out. Sorry to say this, but the code is in very bad shape

Comment: @Vikhram here is a link for the project only 81kb size in winrar http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=93560628512665266582

Comment: @Vikhram here is a direct link to download http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=93560628512665266582&t=9356062851266526658208785

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in the code. I will only focus on the ones relevant to your question. Also, I am trying to keep as much as your own code as possible, so you can better understand the difference between your code and suggested code

1. You should setup your grid only once in the constructor and then add the required row data into it. Currently you are setting up the columns repeatedly - which is what makes your DataGridViewLinkColumn work.

**Your Code:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < countriesCodes.Length; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Status";
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Country";
    var countryName = codeToFullNameMap[countriesCodes[i]];
    string[] row = new string[] { "Ready", countryName };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    DataGridViewLinkColumn dgvLink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
    dgvLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
    dgvLink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
    dgvLink.HeaderText = "Link Data";
    dgvLink.Name = "SiteName";
    dgvLink.LinkColor = Color.Blue;
    dgvLink.TrackVisitedState = true;
    dgvLink.Text = lines[i];
    dgvLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvLink);
}
```

**Better and Corrected code:**

```
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Status";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Country";

DataGridViewLinkColumn dgvLink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
dgvLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
dgvLink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
dgvLink.HeaderText = "Link Data";
dgvLink.Name = "SiteName";
dgvLink.LinkColor = Color.Blue;
dgvLink.TrackVisitedState = true;
dgvLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = false;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvLink);
dataGridView1.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

for (int i = 0; i < countriesCodes.Length; i++) {
    var countryName = codeToFullNameMap[countriesCodes[i]];
    string[] row = new string[] { "Ready", countryName, lines[i] };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

2. In the `client_DownloadFileCompleted` function, you should replace your code with my code

**Your Code:**

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = 
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.SelectionForeColor = Color.Green;
```

**Corrected Code:**

```
var row = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .First(r => r.Cells[2].Value.Equals(url));
row.Cells[0].Value = "Downloaded";
row.Cells[0].Style.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

This should get you the desired behavior. As you see, the variable `row` should have the correct row corresponding to the `url`. You can change the required cell text and style as you please - to handle error case as well as successful download case